# Raspbian python script overloading RAM

Tags: python, ram

I have python script, which writes serial data into text file, kinda logger. When I run it on raspberry pi in about 12 hrs it overloads all RAM of the raspberry and it hangs up (slows down) the board. Initially I thought that is global variables overload memory, however no, that was not, then I thought that might be writing long strings into variable, eliminated it too, cutting down initial functionality did not solve the memory overloading problem.
Could guru suggest what can be wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox, Checkbutton, Radiobutton, Progressbar
from tkinter import scrolledtext, messagebox, ttk, filedialog, Menu, Tk, 
Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW, colorchooser
import serial, time, math
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from guiLoop import guiLoop
import glob

ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial()

......

.......


........


@guiLoop
def list_ser():
    while 1:
        if ser_connect == 1:
            try:
                send_com('R_S')
            except:
                print('Serial port is close!')                  
        yield 1


#Create window:    
window = Tk()

#window.state('zoomed')    #for windows
#window.attributes('-zoomed', True) #for linux
show_all = tk.BooleanVar()
show_all.set(True)

..........

...........

............

#------------------Tab7-------------------------------------------
tab7 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab7, text='LINE from FILE')  

 #scrolledtext demo:
txt3 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(tab7, width=40, height=10)
txt3.insert(INSERT, '')
txt3.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, height=860, width=1900)

#btn_get2 = Button(tab7, text='READ LINE FROM FILE', 
command=partial(read_line,'0','10','20')) # delete logs in log file
btn_get2 = Button(tab7, text='READ LINE FROM FILE', 
command=partial(read_line,'20')) # delete logs in log file
btn_get2.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.91, height=70, width=200)

#----------------------------------------------------------------- 
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

set_conf()
#serial_ports()
#get_logs()
list_ser(window)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeWindow)
window.mainloop()
```